# Conversion of object to multiple dimensional array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, asp.net-ajax, webmethod

I am passing multidimensional array in web method as object type. I want to convert this object type to multiple array in the method.

The method, which does the conversion:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Save(object arr)
{
  Dictionary<string, object> value = (Dictionary<string, object>)arr;
  return ""; 
}
```

The client-side code:

```
//ajax method
var arr=new Array();

 var table = document.getElementById('table');
    for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        arr[r] = new Array(10);
        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
            arr[r][c]=table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML;
        }
    }
    console.log(arr);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "salary.aspx/Save",
    data: JSON.stringify({ arr: arr }),
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);            
    }
});
```

The error message is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Object,System.Object]'.

Comment: You wont be able to directly cast it. Try looping and iterating over individual items.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to create your inner array differently:

```
//ajax method
var arr=new Array();

 var table = document.getElementById('table');
    for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        arr[r] = {};
        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
            arr[r][c]=table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML;
        }
    }
    console.log(arr);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "salary.aspx/Save",
    data: JSON.stringify({ arr: arr }),
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);            
    }
});
```

Then you should be able to do something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Save(object arr)
{
    object[] table = (object[])arr;

    // now the the object contains all your row values as an object.

    return ""; 
}
```

Comment: This code is untested, but the stringify should be putting a single dimensional array down with each row represented as an object.